# How can I filter out the small Hawaiian islands with get_acs?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, tidycensus, tigris

Can you use the `resolution` argument in `get_acs()` to filter out the small islands in the Hawaiian archipelago?

I might have found a bug in `tidycensus`, one of my favorite packages.

I was mapping U.S congressional districts using `tidycensus`'s `get_acs()` function, but I was getting that long archipelago northwest of Hawaii. I tried following [Kyle Walker's tip](https://walker-data.com/census-r/mapping-census-data-with-r.html) to include the `resolution = "20m"` argument to filter out the small islands, but the archipelago wouldn't go away. I eventually just grabbed the geometry using the `congressional_districts()` function and joined the `get_acs()` data.

MRE:

```
#map with too many islands
cds <- get_acs(
  geography = "congressional district",
  variables = "B01003_001",
  geometry = TRUE,
  resolution = "20m"
) %>% shift_geometry()

cds %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf()
```

Bad map:

[image: img1]

What worked:

```
#map with the right number of islands
cds2 <- congressional_districts(cb = TRUE,
                                resolution = "20m") %>% shift_geometry()

cds2 %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf()
```

Good map:

[image: img2]

Comment: This doesn't seem like a bug in the package, just a matter of you changing function arguments. `tidycensus` calls that return geometries use calls from the `tigris` package, which downloads shapefiles from the Census Bureau [TIGER files](https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/tiger-line-file.html). These come in 2 types: more detailed shapes, or less-detailed [cartographic boundary files](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/geography/technical-documentation/naming-convention/cartographic-boundary-file.html), corresponding to `tigris`'s `cb` argument...

Comment: For most tigris functions, the default is `cb = FALSE`, meaning the more detailed shapes are downloaded. That was the argument used in your first case. In your second, when you changed to `cb = TRUE`, you downloaded the less detailed version, the CB file, which doesn't retain those very small areas. AFAIK the `resolution` argument only pertains to the CB files. from the tigris docs: "The resolution of the cartographic boundary file (if cb == TRUE). Defaults to '500k'; options include '5m' (1:5 million) and '20m' (1:20 million)."

Comment: Actually, my 2nd comment isn't totally correct. `tidycensus:::use_tigris` calls tigris functions with a default `cb = TRUE`, in contrast to most tigris functions' own defaults. CB files still have those small islands; it appears where they get lost is in `shift_geometry` [here](https://github.com/walkerke/tigris/blob/227b8fda7af9a35baf50bf07fdf539fb08afa9ea/R/shift_geometry.R#L229) with rescaling and intersecting geometries. All that is to say that if you want geometries altered in a specific way, such as filtering them, you should probably do that yourself separately

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this in the latest CRAN release of **tigris** (sent it in last week); if you re-install **tigris** your original code will return the desired results.